# Wordpress always returning 404 page for a specific url

Tags: permalinks

In my WordPress setup a URL, let's just say `/24-hour-security/` is always returning 404 response. I checked, the page is there and it's also public.

No other page is having such issue. I also tried creating a new page with different URL with the same content. But still the new page is also returning the 404 page. Does anybody have idea why its happening.

My permalink setting is `/%postname%/`

Comment: Just for giggles: Go to Settings->Permalinks and - without changing anything - Click "Save Changes" and try visiting the page again.

Comment: I did this the first thing and it didn't worked either. Thanks for your reply.